# Expectation problems in probability.

Tags: probability

Dan tosses a coin $n$ times independently, while the probability for a unique tail is $1\over 3$. For $1\le k\le n$, let us denote the number of sub-sequence of length $k$ of H's. For example, if n=5 and the results are $HHHTH$ then $N_2=2$. Prove that for $1\le k\le n$, $E[N_k]=(n-k+1)3^{-k}$. I though I was getting somewhere, but I am having troubles understanding what exactly I am doing.

I was given that $E(X)=\sum_{\omega\in \Omega}X(\omega)P(\omega)$, but what is $\Omega$? The expectation definitions are so obscured and confusing. I could really use your help. (I arrived at something but didn't understand a thing so it would be a waste of time.)

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: Hint: Let $H_i^k=\{X_{i-k}=\cdots=X_{i-1}=X_i=H\}$ and $T_i^k=\{X_{i-k}=\cdots=X_{i-1}=X_i=H\}$ then $$N_k=\sum_{i=k+1}^n\mathbf 1_{H_i^k}+\mathbf 1_{T_i^k}.$$ Since $P(H_i^k)=(1-p)^k$ and $P(T_i^k)=p^k$ with $p=\frac13$, this almost sure identity yields $$E(N_k)=(n-k+1)(p^k+(1-p)^k).$$

Comment: I mislead you a little, I am sorry. I am looking for the number of sub-sequences with H's, not H's or T's, but thank you, it is helpful.

Comment: Then forget the events $T_i^k$ (and replace $3^{-k}$ in your answer by $(2/3)^k$).

Comment: But why is P(H's) is $(1-p)^k$? I didn't want there to be one subsequence of $H$'s, but to take all the k-length sub-sequences with H's. Does it take it into consideration?

Comment: Indeed it does. Hint: reread the definition of $H_i^k$ (no idea what your `H's` means).

Comment: Given the results of the tosses is a sequence of Heads and Tails, I put $N_k$ to represent the number of times a sub-sequence of k sequential heads of the sequence aforementioned show up. If the sequence is HHHTH, then $N_2=2$ because I have **HH**HTH and I have H**HH**TH. Does it take that into account?

Comment: Please read: `Indeed it does`. (You know what, some of us can read the statement of an exercise...)

Comment: You said you have no idea what my H's means, which led me to believe, together with my last edits and correction, that there was a misunderstanding. I never questioned your understanding skill. I don't want to take it personal- that is unpleasant. I really appreciate your help and explanations. I will not bother you with it any further if it is not welcome... Thank you so far.

Comment: Did you get the hint?

Comment: I did, but I didn't understand how the probability is actually computed.

Comment: The probability of each $H_i^k$, you mean? Well, $H_i^k=\{X_{i-k}=H\}\cap\cdots\cap\{X_{i-1}=H\}\cap\{X_{i}=H\}$ hence, by independence of the sequence $(X_n)$, one gets $P(H_i^k)=$ $____$ ...

Comment: Okay. That as I understand gives the chance for one subsequence of length k, right?